# mysql: get all rows into 1 column

Tags: sql, mysql, string-concatenation

- post (id_post, title)
- tag (id_tag, name)
- post_tag (id_post_tag, id_post, id_tag)

Lets suppose that id_post 3 has 4 linked tags 1,2,3,4 (soccer, basket, tennis and golf).

Is there a way to return something like this in ONE row?

- **col 1** id_post = 3
- **col 2** tags = soccer basket tennis golf

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT p.id_post
         GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.name SEPARATOR ' ')
    FROM POST p
    JOIN POST_TAG pt ON pt.id_post = p.id_post
    JOIN TAG t ON t.id_tag = pt.id_post_tag
GROUP BY p.id_post
```

Be aware that the default separator is a comma, so you have to define a single space if you don't want that between the tag names.

Documentation:

- [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: worked great! just one more doubt... how do i limit the amount of tags, for example: 3 -- i tried to use a LIMIT approach but it won't work.

Comment: @andufo: You have to use a variable to provide analytical functionality because it doesn't natively exist in MySQL.